# How to print 6 rows of 7 numbers with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I must write a program that accepts a number, n, where -6 < n < 2. The program must print out the numbers n to n+41 as 6 rows of 7 numbers. The first row must contain the values n to n+6, the second, the values n+7 to n+7+6, and so on.

That is, numbers are printed using a field width of 2, and are right-justified.  Fields are separated by a single space. There are no spaces after the final field.

Output: 
 Enter the start number: -2

```
-2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  

 5  6  7  8  9 10 11

12 13 14 15 16 17 18 

19 20 21 22 23 24 25 

26 27 28 29 30 31 32 

33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

The numbers need to be directly lined under each other.
I have absolutely no idea how to do this

This is my code so far:

```
start = int(input('Enter the start number: '))
for n in range(n,n+41):
```

If you could help me I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not allowed to use a library to tabulate the numbers for you and are expected to do the logic yourself.

You need to print 6 rows of numbers. Start by determining the first number of each row. That is given by `range(n,n+42,7)` (note, not `n+41`). For starting value -2, those are the numbers -2, 5, 12, 19, 26, 33. Every other number in the row is just the next 6 integers. If the first number in the row is `leftmost` then the entire row is given by `range(leftmost, leftmost + 7)`. So the first row those are the numbers -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

To print 6 rows of 7 numbers you need a loop with 6 iterations, one for each value of `leftmost`. Inside that loop you print the other numbers. The only complication is all of the numbers in the list must be followed by a space, *except the last*. So that has to get special treatment.

You need to specify format `{0:2d}` to ensure that "numbers are printed using a field width of 2".

```
n = -2
for leftmost in range(n,n+42,7):
    for value in range(leftmost,leftmost + 6):
        print("{0:2d}".format(value), end=" ")
    print("{0:2d}".format(leftmost+6))

-2 -1  0  1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31 32
33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Comment: wow, that's makes much better sense, thank you for making me understand. I really appreciate your help,

Comment: There is an edit to the answer because there were too many spaces between the numbers. Spec says *fields are separated by a single space* and there were two.

Comment: Keeping strictly to the spec, however arbitrary it might seem, is only sometimes important, but is always a matter of pride. (Unless it is clearly stupid, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

check the `tabulate` library [here](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate), you can use it to format the output - the `tablefmt="plain"` parameter produces a very similar table.

If you store the numbers in a `list` you can use [list slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) to get the rows of 7 numbers each and put those in an another list to satisfy the format that `tabulate` is expecting

```
from tabulate import tabulate

n = 2

while not -6 < n < 2:
    n = int(input('Please submit a number greater than -6 and smaller than 2:\n'))

number_list, output_list = [], []

for i in range(42):
    number_list.append(n + i)

for i in range(6):
    output_list.append(number_list[i*7:i*7+7])

print()
print(
    tabulate(
        output_list, 
        tablefmt='plain'
    )
)
```

---

```
Please submit a number greater than -6 and smaller than 2:
-3                                                        
-3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3                                
 4   5   6   7   8   9  10                                
11  12  13  14  15  16  17                                
18  19  20  21  22  23  24                                
25  26  27  28  29  30  31                                
32  33  34  35  36  37  38
```